# Kernel of endomorphism for polynomials from $f(x)$ to $f(2x+1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, change-of-basis

I am looking for a kernel of a map, producing $f(2x+1)$ out of $f(x)$. where $f(x)$ is an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$. I thought of trying to write this transformation as a matrix and then to figure out the kernel, but I  struggled already at this point at finding the matrix.
Thanks for help

Comment: You don't need to write up the matrix. For which polynomials $f$ will $f(2x+1)$ be the constant zero polynomial?

Comment: Hello Berci and thanks. For constant zero polynomials?

Comment: Yes, only for that. Hence the kernel is trivial.

Comment: thanks a lot a quick support!

Comment: Btw, if you now calculate the matrix (just feed the transformation by the basis elements: $1,x,x^2, \dots$), then the trivial kernel will immediately tell you it's an invertible matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of the linear operator in question is the set of polynomials $p$ up to degree $n$ with $p(2x+1)=0$ identically. Comparing coefficients, starting with $x^n$ and working downwards, yields that all the coeffients of $p$ are zero, so the kernel consists only of the zero polynomial. (The map $x\mapsto2x+1$ is invertible, another way to see that the kernel is trivial.)

Comment: thank you for the answer